# Including R code in latex

Tags: r, rstudio

I have some problems by inverting my `R` code into latex and than copying the code of the pdf back into `R`. I used lstlistning to read the `R` code and since it did not show the `-`, I used this code:

```
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother
```

The `pdf` file it looks fine except that spaces now appear as `_`, however when I now copy the code back to `Rstudio`, it doesn't run. It has more spaces and when I multiplied in the Rcode by using `*`, it doesn't show this by copying the code back.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: the code I used for the -, I just copied from this website since this question was already asked earlier

Comment: My welcome (and I think of all users) into TeX.SE website.

Comment: Copy-pasting from a PDF is difficult to get right, but that is an inherent limitation of PDF viewers.

Comment: I think I will just attach the real R files to my email as well in case my teacher wants to run it, however if someone know how the problem with the spaces can be fixed this would be nice.

Comment: (1) Do you  know `knitr`?  (2) You can attach the R code to the pdf file. Run `texdoc attachfile` and `texdoc attachfile2`